# How to use a Provider inside of provider

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ionic2, which is Angular2, but this question is more Angular2 than Ionic framework. I have a provider such as this:

```
import {Injectable, Provider, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyFirstProvider{

  constructor( @Inject(Http) http) {
      this.http = http;
  }
.
.
.
```

I have another provider such as this:

```
import {Injectable, Provider, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MySecondProvider{

  constructor( @Inject(Http) http) {
      this.http = http;
  }

  myCoolFunction(){
    console.log('I am one cool function'); 
  }
.
.
.
```

How can I use MySecondProvider's myCoolFunctions inside of MyFirstProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By injecting it

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstProvider{

  constructor(private http:Http, 
      private mySecond: MySecondProvider) {}

  someMethod(){
    this.mySecond.myCoolFunctions();
  }
}
```

These classes are services, not providers. These services can and need to be registered as providers. A provider is a combination of key and value construction instruction.
When DI looks up a type (key) it searches a components injector and its parent injectors until it finds one with a matching key and then returns its instance (the service).

Comment: I tried this previously, but got the error:browser_adapter.js:77 Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for MySecondProvider!
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: DI Exception. I imported the provider without a problem, my IDE even found the location of the provider, so the second provider is imported into the first.

Comment: I tried both   constructor( @Inject(Platform) platform, @Inject(Http) http, @Inject(Providersqlstorage) providersqlstorage )
 and   constructor( @Inject(Platform) platform, @Inject(Http) http, providersqlstorage:Providersqlstorage )

Comment: As mentioned you need to register the services as providers somewhere, for example `@App({... providers: [MyFirstProvider, MySecondProvider]})`. I don't know Ionic but I think this should work.